# localStorage breaks github page

Tags: javascript, local-storage, github-pages

So I have a GitHub page with a game on it, and I want to use localStorage to store user’s scores. However, this has caused some problem with the script because the game no longer works and things that should be printed on the screen aren’t printed (using document.write). This is the code which I added:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("highscore") !=== null) {
    document.write("Your highscore is " + localStorage.getItem("highscore"));
}
else {
    document.write("Play the game to set a highscore");
}
//game code
if (testhighscore && localStorage.getItem("highscore") > myGameArea.frameNo) {
    localStorage.setItem("highscore", myGameArea.frameNo)
    document.write("Your highscore is now " +  localStorage.getItem("highscore"))
}
```

How (if possible) can I fix this, and why does it happen?

Comment: note that there's a type in the first line, ```!===``` should be ```!==``` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Nonidentity). Apart from that, do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I fixed that, but it still doesn’t work. I’m going to try running it somewhere other than GitHub to find errors

Comment: I made it so the page should no longer break. I just need to figure out how to update high scores

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using sessionStorage instead? My app worked locally but it broke once deployed to github pages when I was using localStorage. My problem was that during testing, a value from a previous session was persisted to the app from storage. Using localStorage hid a bug in my code that I was able to fix after switching to sessionStorage and fixing my logic.

Formally, the difference is:

- sessionStorage maintains a separate storage area for each given
  origin that's available for the duration of the page session (as long
  as the browser is open, including page reloads and restores).
- localStorage does the same thing, but persists even when the browser 
  is closed and reopened.
  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Comment: I just replaced all instances of localStorage with sessionStorage and that fixed the issue, deployed to GitHub Pages just as expected. I wonder why GH Pages doesn't seem to be compatible with localStorage.